# Is an algorithm whose time complexity increases with input but with a limit considered O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

if a function's statements execution increases with input but with a limit, would it be considered O(n) or O(1)?

for example:

```
void func(int n)
    {
        if (n > 1000)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                //do thing
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                //do same thing
            }
        }
    }
```

is this function O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: I would say O(n).

Comment: I agree, it is always O(n)  when n is ranged between 1000 and infinity. So I would say it as O(n)

Comment: Just look at the definition of big-O. Hint: there is a limit in there.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. what if the limit was higher (let's say close to maximum int)?

Comment: Big-O is mathematical notation for mathematical objects called functions. It concerns itself with behaviour of functions at **infinity**. This notation operates with integers, not "ints". There is no such thing as maximum integer. The notion of Big-O is not applicable to computer programs that operate on computers of finite size.

Comment: aren't all computers of finite size? are you saying Big-O isn't useful outside of theory applications?

Comment: The loop always takes <= 1000 steps. O(n) would go up to infinity. It is O(1).

Comment: Big-O is an abstraction. As any abstraction, it has limited applicability to the real world. It is useful within some limits and less useful outside of those limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is O(1), not O(n).

Big-O analysis is *asymptotic*:  it intentionally ignores an arbitrarily large initial section of the performance function, in order to accurately describe the large-scale behavior.